# How to make an object that can fly, lay an egg, and do stuff (Inheritance)

Tags: java

Im working on Inheritance right now in Java and this is the cod that I have that describes a bird

```
public class Bird {
    public void fly() {
        System.out.println("the Bird flies");
    }
    public void layEgg() {
        System.out.println("The bird layed an egg");
    }
    public void doStuff() {
        System.out.println("Doing some stuff...");
        fly(); layEgg();
    }

}
```

this is my main class and how do I create a bird object that can fly, lay an egg, and do stuff.

```
public class Exploration {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ????
    }

}
```

Comment: `new Bird()` ... perhaps consider a tutorial or book (that covers this)?

Comment: Which would be just *any* tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

To create a new bird instance, put

```
Bird myBird = new Bird();
```

To make your bird do stuff, put:

```
myBird.fly(); 
myBird.doStuff();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Exploration {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Bird myBird = new Bird ()
      myBird.fly ();
    }

}
```

or

```
class Bird {
    public void layEgg() {
        System.out.println("The bird layed an egg");
    }
}

class Falcon extends Bird {
    public void layEgg() {
        System.out.println("The falcon layed an egg");
    }
    public void fly() {
        System.out.println("The falcon flies");
    }
}

class Turkey extends Bird {
    public void layEgg() {
        System.out.println("The turkey layed an egg");
    }
}

public class Exploration {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Bird myFirstBird = new Falcon ()
      myFirstBird.fly ();
      Bird myOtherBird = new Turkey ()
      myOtherBird.fly (); // Compile error: 
                          // I didn't know turkeys couldn't fly
    }

}
```

Comment: +1 for a comprehensive example, but -1 because you didn't notice that `myFirstBird.fly()` won't compile either :)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make the bird object like so:

```
Bird birdObject = new Bird();
```

You can replace "birdObject" with whatever you want to call it.
You can then do such things like

```
birdObject.fly();
```

or

```
birdObject.layEgg();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
         Bird b = new Bird();
         b.fly();
         b.layEgg();
         b.doStuff();
    }
```